# Finding nearest 10 observations that occurred 2 years before original observation using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder?

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, nearest-neighbor

I have a point sample of house sales (~42k points over 9 year period) with a date field(integer), and for each point I want to find the 10 nearest houses within a year of sale and also which were sold before the house in question.

The plan is to use the iterate feature in ModelBuilder to select each point, and also the sample of near features, run the generate near table for the 10 closest houses, append to a table and label using the value output field from the iterator, and loop again.

How do I generate the near features sample for each individual house?

The table is ordered by objectid=1 is the most recent sale and the highest objectid is the oldest sale.

Comment: Were you able to extract the date field during each iteration?

Comment: Hi smiller, No I wasnt. I would like to reference the date field from each iteration. So I would like to select if date field< ((value of date field in iteration)+365) and date field>(value of datefield in iteration).

The problem is in the SQL expression box in the tool for select by attribute I don't know how to reference that value. If I join the value bubble from the iterator to the select tool as an expression it doesn't let me edit it. Very lost at the moment